# Why there are power supplies that have rs232 and USB interfaces?

Tags: power-supply, rs232

Sometimes power supplies have USB and RS232 interfaces, what is the reason?

## edit

In [this video](https://youtu.be/g94mpom2Ahs?t=2m7s) of eev blog, david jones was doing a teardown of one which has rs232 and usb interfaces..

Comment: Can you give us a link to an example?

Comment: @ThePhoton check the edit..

Comment: Suppose you make a product and your datasheet says it works at 5 V +/- 10%. How would you imagine testing that capability? Suppose you have to test 100 (or 1000) units per hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would typically be to allow them to be remotely programmable from a PC, e.g. [this TDK-Lambda Z+400 supply](https://www.us.tdk-lambda.com/lp/news/2012_release08.htm) which provides USB, RS-232 and RS-485 interfaces.

Programmability is very useful in setting up automated testing.  Sort of like having a DAC with a large current capability.